# problem with csv file to open it with csv.reader

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
filename = (r"C:\Users\Z\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64- bit)\diabetes.csv")
raw_data = open(filename, 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(raw_data, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
x = list(reader)
data = (np.array(x)).astype('float')
print(data.shape)
```

But it errors:

```
----> 7 x = list(reader)
Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

When I change `'rb'` to `'rt'`:

```
raw_data = open(filename, 'rt')
```

It says:

```
----> 8 data = (np.array(x)).astype('float')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Pregnancies'
```

And when I delete `.astype('float')`, the result is `(769, 9)` but the expected result is `(768, 9)`.

It counts the header as data. Can you tell me why?

Comment: The answer is in your error message. You opened the file in binary mode.

Comment: look i changed it in text mode also and also in read mode but the second and third problem still stays

Comment: You haven't given us any sample input but it appears that your data begins with a row of headers including the word `Pregnancies`. As the next message says, you can't convert that to a float. So if you don't convert it to a float and fail, `numpy` counts the header as data and so the shape is off by one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do following:

```py
reader = csv.reader(raw_data, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
x = list(reader)
```

try

```py
reader = csv.reader(raw_data, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
next(reader)
x = list(reader)
```

which should skip the header of csvfiles.

It is described @ https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.__next__

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your mode of opening the file. You opened the file in `'rb'` mode.
`'rb'` is used only for binary files and CSV file type is not binary.

Use :

```
raw_data = open(filename, 'r')
```

OR

```
raw_data = open(filename)
```

This is because the file is by default opened in read mode by `open()` function.

And about header being taken as data, use

```
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ','[,other parameters])
data = []
for i in reader:
  if i[0] = "You first cell's data":
    pass
  else:
    data.append(i)
```

Now you can use the list to create Numpy Arrays

Comment: @BerylAmend Please give your data. I think the problem is you have given strings and trying to convert it to float which triggers the error. And the error in your answer is because I expect after you removed `.astype('float')` it is taking header as a row. Have you tried the code I suggested for ignoring the header?

Comment: yes dear i tried your answer and i turned = for if to == and also for my first cell' data i first put the whole header and the answer was(769, 9). then i changed it and put just the first cell's data it worked as u said. but in this method all other column's headers are not count as  data?bcs when it counts the first column goes through  the second column that has header and so on.